# Sending a Spark DataFrame via Email

Tags: scala, jakarta-mail

I am working on this project where I need to get the table data in a spark dataframe and send it in a mail. The language to be used is Scala.

The dataframe to hold the table data is as follows:-

```
val sqlDfUT = hiveCon.sql("select * from UserTable")
```

I need to send "sqlDfUT" as a message body in a mail.

The code for sending the mail is:

```
sendScalaMail("monitor@foo.com","Users Data Sent : \n " + sqlDfUT +
                    ",\nMail sent from host: " + java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(),
                    "12525","Hive Data Checking completed for given User: 12525" )

def sendScalaMail (mailSender:String, strMailBody:String, mailIdList:String, strMailSubj:String)={

if ((mailIdList == null) && (mailIdList.equals(""))){

  writeToLog("Email ID not defined")
}
writeToLog("<----Sender---->"+mailSender)
writeToLog("<----strMailBody---->"+strMailBody)
writeToLog("<----mailIdList---->"+mailIdList)
writeToLog("<----strMailSubj---->"+strMailSubj)

val smtpHost:String = "mail.foo.com"
val prop:Properties = new Properties()
prop.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost)
prop.put("mail.debug", "false")
var session:Session = Session.getInstance(prop)
var toPersonList:Array[String] = mailIdList.split(",")

var toMailListSB:StringBuffer = new StringBuffer()
var toPersonName:String = ""
var toMailId:String = ""
var index:Int = 0

for(index <- 0 to toPersonList.length){

  toPersonName = toPersonList(index).asInstanceOf[String]
  toMailId = toPersonName+"@mail.foo.com"
  toMailListSB.append(toMailId)
  toMailListSB.append(";")

}
try{
  var msg:MimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session)
  msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailSender))
  var toList:Array[String] = toMailListSB.toString().split(",")
  var address:Array[InternetAddress] = new InternetAddress(toList.length.toString()).asInstanceOf[Array[InternetAddress]]
  var i:Int = 0
  for(i <- 0 to toList.length){
    address(i) = new InternetAddress(toList(i))
  }
  msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address)
  msg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
  msg.setSubject(strMailSubj)
  msg.setSentDate(new Date())       
  msg.setContent(strMailBody, "text/html")

  Transport.send(msg)

}
catch{
  case me:MessagingException =>{
    me.printStackTrace()
    writeToLog("<---Error in method sendScalaMail--->"+me)
  }
} }
```

However, I am getting the error in line

```
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address)
```

and the error message is

```
overloaded method value setRecipients with alternatives: (x$1: javax.mail.Message.RecipientType,x$2: String)Unit <and> (x$1: javax.mail.Message.RecipientType,x$2: Array[javax.mail.Address])Unit cannot be applied to (javax.mail.Message.RecipientType, Array[javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress])
```

I will be really glad if I could get any guidance. Thank you

Comment: Error is not connected with Spark, but with Mailing API. BTW you want only one long, not full DataFrame

Comment: updated the question, i want to send the dataframe which has the complete table data (the records are less though) in the mail.

Comment: the type of `address` is not correct, it should be `Array[Address]`

Comment: @Ritesh Satapathy , can you tell me the details for host and port, like where should I look into, to get them. Thanks.

Comment: @KanavSharma you can use smtp host and port for the mail server where it is hosted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var address:Address = new InternetAddress(toMailId).asInstanceOf[Address]
```

this worked for me!! Thank you Raphael :)

Answer (score 1):

@Ritesh,

I tried similar thing using javamailAPI thing but in my case its not sending an dataframe and its expecting a String to be a message body

Below is  my code

```
  var bodyText = "Delta File"
  val username = "test@gmail.com"
  val password = "test"
  val smtpHost = "smtp.gmail.com"

 // Set up the mail object
 val properties = System.getProperties
 properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost)
 properties.put("mail.smtp.user", username);
 properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
 properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
 properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587")
 properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

 val auth:Authenticator = new Authenticator() {
 override def getPasswordAuthentication = new
    PasswordAuthentication(username, password)
 }

 val session = Session.getInstance(properties,auth)
val message = new MimeMessage(session)

 // Set the from, to, subject, body text
 message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test@****.com"))
 message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "sim@****.com")
 message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
 message.setSubject("Count of DeviceIDs we are sent daily")
 df = spark.sql("select * from test table")
 message.setContent(df, "text/html")

 // And send it
 Transport.send(message)
```

in case of text message its working fine