# Applying Email Notification in spark scala with Error message

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can i send an email notification if error occured in spark. i am using spark dataframe and version is spark 1.6. and scala it is a maven project.

i want to send an email with error message when spark job failed.

please help me.

Comment: This may be duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928805/sending-a-spark-dataframe-via-email

Comment: @sangam.gavini: i don't need to send output of query, i am trying to send an email notification whenever error occured in spark job....kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a reference from below gitHub code

https://github.com/NikhilSuthar/ScalaMail

Comment: Thanks a lot...... if possible Please help me how can i configure log4j so when error occur mail can be triggered.